# Ignite Openfire XMPP access logs

Tags: openfire

I can't find this answer anywhere, and I'm going to assume that they don't exist, but does the Ignite Openfire XMPP Server have some form of access logs - where I can see what users are trying to authenticate? Sure there are error logs, warn, and info logs - but none of them seem to provide access logs.

I'm trying to debug some issues where it appears users aren't able to authenticate sometimes, but I have no way of seeing if they are even hitting the server.

Answer (score 1):

Install the Debugger Plugin from the Admin console. Enable Debugg Logging under "Logs" in the Panel.
Auditing Packages could be also very useful.